# Python, SQL: INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE UPDATE with dictionary

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

Help me please. I need to insert dictionary into table, or update it, if exists. As I find in stackoverflow, there is a many questions how to insert dict into sql table, but I can't find, how to do insert..update if exists with dictionary. Anybody have ideas?

There is my actual code (which doesn't work):

```
with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
    item['added'] = unicode(int((datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()))
    columns, values = u', '.join(item.keys()), u', '.join(item.values())
    item.pop('added', None)
    item.pop('link', None)
    item['updated_at'] = datetime.datetime.now()
    exists_item = zip(item.keys(), item.values())
    update_query = u', '.join([u'{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in exists_item])
    query = u'INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {}'.format(
        DB_NAME, columns, values, update_query
    )
    cursor.execute(query)
```

I have syntax error, because values part is not properly escaped. but if I use one of the best solution to insert dict (make a placeholders with '?' and then use execute(query, values)) I've got other error:
`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is incorrect syntax in MySQL query, but not in merge approach. Indeed, `INSERT INTO ... DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` is one of the methods for merge table. If you check that return `print(query)`, then will see error.

Your query:

```
INSERT INTO DB_NAME (added) VALUES (1455102006) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at=2016-02-10 11:00:06.594000
```

How see mysql doesn't parse date. Date should be in quotes or use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Right query:

```
INSERT INTO DB_NAME (added) VALUES (1455102006) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at='2016-02-10 11:00:06.594000'
```

For this you may replace line code on:

```
update_query = u', '.join([u"{}='{}'".format(k, v) for k, v in exists_item])
```

with adding quotes for update value.

Answer (score 0):

All in one function:

```
def insert_row(table, db, row, **kwargs):
    placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(row))
    columns = ', '.join(row.keys())
    ignore = 'IGNORE' if kwargs.get('insertIgnore') else ''
    onDuplicate = ''
    onDuplicateUpdate = kwargs.get('onDuplicateUpdate', [])
    values = list(row.values())
    if len(onDuplicateUpdate) > 0:
        updates = {}
        for k in onDuplicateUpdate:
            updates[k] = row[k]
        updatePlaceholders = ('=%s, '.join(updates.keys())) + '=%s'
        values.extend(list(updates.values()))
        onDuplicate = f'  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {updatePlaceholders}'

    sql = "INSERT %s INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s ) %s ;" % (ignore, table, columns, placeholders, onDuplicate)
    # print('sql', sql)
    rowInserted = db.cursor().execute(sql, values)
    db.commit()
    return rowInserted == 1
```

Usage Example:

```
onDuplicateUpdate = ['city', 'address', 'timestamp']
insert_row('users', db, user_details, onDuplicateUpdate=onDuplicateUpdate, insertIgnore=True)
```